# How to arrange pushButtons to be in a specific portion of a window?

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

In this code, I have arranged four buttons in the `QVBoxLayout` and the result is in the picture [The buttons covered the whole window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrXRa.png). I made another window also but that was in the `QtDesigner` and that design doesn't cover the whole screen. Instead, it arranges the buttons in a specific portion of the screen. [Here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYwWq.png). How to write the code of the buttons to be in a specific portion of a window?

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 QVBoxLayout")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("picture.png"))

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        b1 = QPushButton("First")
        b2 = QPushButton("Second")
        b3 = QPushButton("Third")
        b4 = QPushButton("Fourth")

        vbox.addWidget(b1)
        vbox.addWidget(b2)
        vbox.addWidget(b3)
        vbox.addWidget(b4)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The right question is: what are you going to do with *the other* portion of the window? Layouts exist for specific reasons: most importantly, they allow objects to adapt their size based on their requirements *and* the available space, while also ensuring that the minimum size required is always respected. Using fixed geometries is considered *bad practice*, but there are cases for which some empty space is preferred (or required).

Comment: I want another portion for the purpose of the text label, checkbox etc.

Comment: Layouts already take care of everything as soon as objects are inserted. I suggest you to try to use them and understand how they work. Read more on using [layouts in designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). If you want some sort of "placeholder" for widgets that will be dynamically created later, consider a plain empty QWidget.